# SwiftUI Binding in filtered Array not working in subview and parentview at the same time

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

Currently I am in the process of understanding SwiftUI Binding in my App and implementing a "User Detailview". This should show a disable button if the user is not already disabled. This works correctly as long as I don't filter on the parent and detail view in any way for the user status. The two "if-clauses" in the parent and detail view cause the disable button not to disappear after the click. If I leave them out, the code works, but then also shows all users.

I am now looking for a way that my UI displays the disable button according to the user status.

User model:

```
struct User: Identifiable, Codable{
    var id: Int
    var userStatus: UserStatus?
}

enum UserStatus: Codable{
    case active
    case disabled
}
```

Observable object to store all users:

```
class UserManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = []
    
    init(){
        self.users = [ 
             ... 
        ]
    }

    func disableUser(userId: Int){
        if let userIdx = users.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == userId }){
            users[userIdx].userStatus = .disabled
        }
    }
}
```

Parent view:

```
@EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager

...

Vstack{
    ForEach($userManager.users){ $user in
        if(user.userStatus == .active){
            NavigationLink(destination: UserDetailView(user: $user)){
                UserCardView(user: $user)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}
```

User detail view:

```
struct UserDetailView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager
    var user: Binding<User>
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
        if(user.userStatus.wrappedValue == .active){
            Button("Disable"){
                userManager.disableUser(userId: user.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Besides this approach I also tried to use the array filter function. This led to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@Binding var user: User
```

Instead of

```
var user: Binding<User>
```